# In JSF, how to make h:commandButton to send only one field?

Tags: java, validation, jsf, jsf-2

In JSF2 I have a command button, which should send only one field:

```
<h:inputHidden id="dirty" value="#{bean.dirty}" />
<h:commandButton value="Back" immediate="true"
                 action="#{bean.backIfClean}">
  <f:ajax execute="dirty" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This code doesn't work. I change hidden field value by JavaScript, then I want to send it to server. However, it is not even set on bean (`setDirty` is not called).

If I remove `immediate="true"` validation is triggered, which I want to avoid in this case.

Can I somehow avoid validation and send `dirty` field value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work.  If you put immediate on a command button, the values for the input components never get set.  This is a major inconvenience in the framework if you ask me.

The only solution you have is to retrieve the value yourself from the request.

What I don't get is why yu can't do with just the execute.  Normally, only 'dirty' should be validated in that case.  Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

When you put `immediate="true"` on an `UICommand` component, then **only** the `UIInput` fields which *also* have `immediate="true"` will be processed. See also [this summary](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#WhenShouldIUseTheImmediateAttribute).

So, add `immediate="true"` to the `h:inputHidden`.

*(note: untested in combination with `f:ajax`, this is pure theory)*

Comment: It doesn't work. I removed <f:ajax>, added immediate="true" to the hidden input, and it's not sent to the server. setDirty() is never called.

Comment: And without `immediate="true"`? (put the `<f:ajax execute="dirty">` back in, you're only processing the hidden field anyway, so validation shouldn't trigger for other fields)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following approach to send/retrieve one value:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.backIfClean}">
   <f:param name="dirty" value="#{bean.dirty}"/>       
</h:commandButton>
```

Backing Bean code:

```
public String backIfClean()
{
   String dirty = (String)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("dirty");
}
```